# ComputedObject (Error) Error in map(ID=2015_01_05): Image.constant: Parameter 'value' is required

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, modis, time-series

I would like to get 5 to 95 percent Day_1km_LST from MOD11A1, but it show this error:

> ComputedObject (Error) Error in map(ID=2015_01_05): Image.constant:
> Parameter 'value' is required

The Google Earth Engine Code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/98134eed5eb512d7db6561619a7053c6accept_repo=users%2Fsofiaermida%2Flandsat_smw_lst

```
// region
var boundary1=ee.FeatureCollection("users/liukunsheng6/GBA");
var roi = boundary1.geometry();
Map.addLayer(roi,{'color':'grey'}, 'studyArea');
Map.centerObject(roi);

var year = 2015;


var LSTVisPara = {
  min: 290.0,
  max: 310.0,
  palette: [
    '040274', '040281', '0502a3', '0502b8', '0502ce', '0502e6',
    '0602ff', '235cb1', '307ef3', '269db1', '30c8e2', '32d3ef',
    '3be285', '3ff38f', '86e26f', '3ae237', 'b5e22e', 'd6e21f',
    'fff705', 'ffd611', 'ffb613', 'ff8b13', 'ff6e08', 'ff500d',
    'ff0000', 'de0101', 'c21301', 'a71001', '911003'
  ],
};

// remove cloud for MoDIS_lst
var bitwiseExtract = function(input, fromBit, toBit) {
  var maskSize = ee.Number(1).add(toBit).subtract(fromBit);
  var mask = ee.Number(1).leftShift(maskSize).subtract(1);
  return input.rightShift(fromBit).bitwiseAnd(mask);
};
function maskMod_lst(image){
  var lstDay = image.select('LST_Day_1km');
  var qcDay = image.select('QC_Day');
// Let's extract all pixels from the input image where
// Bits 0-1 <= 1 (LST produced of both good and other quality)
// Bits 2-3 = 0 (Good data quality)
// Bits 4-5 Ignore, any value is ok
// Bits 6-7 = 0 (Average LST error ≤ 1K)  
  var qaMask = bitwiseExtract(qcDay, 0, 1).lte(1);
  var dataQualityMask = bitwiseExtract(qcDay, 2, 3).eq(0);
  var lstErrorMask = bitwiseExtract(qcDay, 6, 7).eq(0);
  var mask = qaMask.and(dataQualityMask).and(lstErrorMask);
  return lstDay.updateMask(mask).toFloat().multiply(0.02).subtract(273.15)
  .copyProperties(image)
  .copyProperties(image,["system:time_start"]);
}

//get the 1kmd ailyLST product MOD11A1
var MOD_LST = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD11A1')
                  .filterDate(ee.Date.fromYMD(year,1,1),ee.Date.fromYMD(year+1,1,1))
                  .map(maskMod_lst)
                  .select('LST_Day_1km');

// MO11A1_year composite
var MOD_LST_source = MOD_LST.select('LST_Day_1km').median().clip(roi);
Map.addLayer(MOD_LST_source, LSTVisPara,'LST_Day_1km',false); 

// define the percent function
function removeOutliers(image) {
  var accPctRange = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.percentile([5, 95]),
    geometry: roi, 
    scale: 30, 
    bestEffort: true
  });

  var minVal = ee.Number(accPctRange.get('LST_Day_1km_p5'));
  var maxVal = ee.Number(accPctRange.get('LST_Day_1km_p95'));
  var processedImage = image.updateMask(image.gte(minVal).and(image.lte(maxVal)));
  return processedImage;
}

// cal the median
var lst = MOD_LST.map(removeOutliers)
                .reduce(ee.Reducer.median())
                .clip(roi)
                .rename('LST_Day_1km');

// cal the min and max
var minValImage = lst.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.min(), roi, 1000).get('LST_Day_1km');
var maxValImage = lst.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.max(), roi, 1000).get('LST_Day_1km');

print('Min Value:', minValImage);
print('Max Value:', maxValImage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `LST_Day_1km_p5` and `LST_Day_1km_p95` is `null`. There is probably some image with no unmasked pixels in the collection.

A quick fix to this could be to turn `minVal` and `maxVal` into constant images and use `ee.Algorithms.If()` to ensure they're masked out if they're `null`. Note that this will also mask them out if they're `0` too.

```
  var minVal = accPctRange.getNumber('LST_Day_1km_p5')
  minVal = ee.Image(ee.Algorithms.If(minVal, ee.Image(minVal), ee.Image()))
  var maxVal = accPctRange.getNumber('LST_Day_1km_p95')
  maxVal = ee.Image(ee.Algorithms.If(maxVal, ee.Image(maxVal), ee.Image()))
```

An arguably better solution is to split up `removeOutliers()` into two separate functions. First calculate the percentiles, filter out images where you get `null`, then remove outliers.

```
var lst = MOD_LST
  .map(addPercentiles)
  .filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['LST_Day_1km_p5', 'LST_Day_1km_p95']))
  .map(removeOutliers)
  .reduce(ee.Reducer.median())
  .clip(roi)
  .rename('LST_Day_1km');

function addPercentiles(image) {
  var accPctRange = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.percentile([5, 95]),
    geometry: roi, 
    scale: 30, 
    bestEffort: true
  });
  return image.set(accPctRange)
}

function removeOutliers(image) {
  var minVal = image.getNumber('LST_Day_1km_p5')
  var maxVal = image.getNumber('LST_Day_1km_p95')
  var processedImage = image.updateMask(image.gte(minVal).and(image.lte(maxVal)));
  return processedImage;
}
```